# How to concat javascript array in an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

could someone help me concat an array to another array that is part of a javascript object? So far I have tried:

```
var someObj = {};
someObj.someArray = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];

var randomArray = ['5', '6', '7']


someObj.someArray.concat(randomArray);

console.log(someObj);
```

However, the final object contains the original array, not the original array concated with the `randomArray`.

Here's my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/d8md3r7a/

Comment: `someObj.someArray = someObj.someArray.concat(randomArray);`

Comment: note, the "push" answers below have a limitation that the `randomArray` can't be more than 500000 in length, will result in `RangeError: too many function arguments` error (in firefox, other browsers may have different limits) Sure, 500 thousand is a lot, but it's still a limit that doesn't apply to the concat methods in the answers below

Comment: why? you've never worked with such large arrays? I do, regularly - your handle @Kinduser seems ironic

Comment: Yoda says:  Almost surely, a duplicate this is.

Comment: OP is having problems with arrays containing few elements and you want him to care about 500k?

Comment: If that's "actual code", then I'll eat my keyboard. note: chrome is limited to `125519`

Comment: Whatever. And I clearly doubt that he's going to handle 100k arrays ever in his life. If I'm wrong - I will eat it the keyboard too.

Comment: Edge - `325124`

Comment: Well, sorry for adding information that **you** find useless. If **you** never needed to work with large datasets in javasacript, that's great - but to have a go at me for it is a little juvenile

Comment: @Kinduser - to clarify, your answer is fine, the ones that use `push.apply` or `push(...arg)` are the ones that will face the limitations I have mentioned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) for `Array.prototype.concat`:

> The `concat()` method is used to merge two or more arrays. **This method does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array**. (Emphasis mine)

As you can see, the method does not actually change the array in place. The new array is *returned* from the method, so you'll need to assign the to the returned array like so:

```
someObj.someArray = someObj.someArray.concat(randomArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Array.concat()` doesn't modify the original array but returns the concatenated results. You need to use the **return value of `Array.concat()`** to explicitly set the original object property. Updated your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/d8md3r7a/1/).

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this instead of `.concat()`.

```js
var someObj = {};
someObj.someArray = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
var randomArray = ['5', '6', '7']

randomArray.forEach(v => someObj.someArray.push(v));
  
console.log(someObj);
```

Comment: Not sure why there's downvotes on this, at least this will work regardless of `randomArray` size (unlike the `push.apply` or `push(...arg)` answers)

Answer (score 1):

`concat` makes a new array and is used like this

```
someObj.someArray = someObj.someArray.concat(randomArray);
```

Another way is to modify the array in place by inserting the additional elements.  To do that, use `push` together with `Function.apply` like this:

```
[].push.apply(someObj.someArray, randomArray);
```

`Function.apply` takes two parameters, the first is a `this` value and the second is an array that is used to fill in the function parameters.  Here, `Function.apply` causes the elements of `randomArray` to be unwrapped from the array as (multiple) parameters to the push function, instead of pushing the entire array as a single element.  The `[]` is a trick to create a blank array to grab the push function, instead of the more verbose `someObj.someArray.push` or `Array.prototype.push`.

Answer (score 0):

To echo the answer above.  The use of the .concat() method is definitely the way  to go.  You could also use the ES6 spread operator which can be used like push and concat.  This will give you the results you are looking for.

```
var someObj = {};
someObj.someArray = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];

var randomArray = ['5', '6', '7']


someObj.someArray.push(...randomArray);

console.log(someObj);
```